# Countif with next cell not empty

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-2007

I need to count how many times a string appear within a range but only when the next cell is not empty.

```
A  1
B  5
D  4
A
G  1
B  4
B  8
D
```

So I want for A->1, B->3, D->1, G->1

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a cell formula, this should get you what you need:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A8,"A",B1:B8,"<>")
```

Where `A1:A8` is your letter column, and `B1:B8` is your number column.

*Note this is `COUNTIFS()` (with **S**), not `COUNTIF()` (no **S**).

---

For completeness, this will also work, but can be more convoluted than you may want to work with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A8="A")*(LEN(B1:B8)>0))
```

---

If you're looking for a VB(A) solution, this should work:

```
For i = 1 To 8
    'Replace mySheet and CellCount with the proper variables for your use
    If mySheet.Range("A" & i).Value2 = "A" And Len(mySheet.Range("B" & i)) > 0 Then
        CellCount = CellCount + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you, `=COUNTIFS()` was exactly what I needed :)